# Populating JSON Array into android spinner from MySQL databse(server)

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I'm able to populate the JSON array into spinner value and get the selected item. But i want the id of the item selected in the spinner. Need Help. Thanks

```
{"streams":[{"streamid":"1","streamname":"Engineering"},          
            {"streamid":"2","streamname":"Medical"},     
            {"streamid":"3","streamname":"Science"}]}
```

For example if i select STREAMNAME-Medical then i could get the id of medical i.e STREAMID-2
but every time i get the last stream name and stream id. from JSON map.get("streamid") and ("streamname")

Here is my code:

```
private String streamid, streamname,stream,id,name;
ArrayAdapter<String> streamAdapter;
Spinner sp;

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////

  btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            stream=(String) sp.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println("STREAM="+stream);

            });
}

  try {
            if (c.GetResponse() != null) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(c.GetResponse());
                JSONArray userKey = json.getJSONArray("streams");
                Log.e("GetJason Response", " " + userKey);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp.setPrompt("Select Stream");
                for (int i = 0; i < userKey.length(); ++i)
                {   
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("streamid", userKey.getJSONObject(i).optString("streamid"));
                    map.put("streamname", userKey.getJSONObject(i).optString("streamname"));

                    data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    data.add(map);
                    id = (String) map.get("streamid");
                    name = (String) map.get("streamname");

                    adapter.add(userKey.getJSONObject(i).getString("streamname"));   
                }

                sp.setAdapter(adapter);
                System.out.println("ID="+ id);
                System.out.println("NAME="+name);
            }
```

Comment: you are updating your hashmap in a loop with same values so only the last value remains all other values are replaced with the newer values

Comment: @PramodYadav then how to do it can you please elaborate a bit with code

Comment: Sorry but could you please first clean up your code? What I see directy is that you only put the stream name in your adapter and nothing more. And why this hash map? You could directly place the JSONObject with the two keys in your array. Then you could use this array in your adapter.

Comment: @rmertins How to do it can you modify the code as i'm new to andorid

Comment: It has nothing to do with android. Its java and sorry but refactoring your code is not my job.